# how to check and change color of cell value in kendo ui grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am using kendo ui grid in MVC4 project. Below is my code

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("gridexcel")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ExcelId).Title("Id").Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.status).Title("Status").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(c => c.report_date).Title("Report Date");
        columns.Bound(c => c.code).Width(50);
```

and columns from 1 to 50...
         }

Here i want to check cells of columns from 1 to 50, whether it contains 0 or 1. if 0 then i want to change background color. please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a a jsbin of what you described

http://jsbin.com/zusutigi/17/edit?css,js,output

To accomplish this, first hook into the DataBound event in your kendo mvc wrapper.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/grideventbuilder

```
...
.Name("gridexcel")
.Events(events => events.DataBound(
        @<text>
            onDataBound
            </text>
            ))
        )
...
```

Then to check all cells in columns 1 - 50 for a 1 or a 0 you would add this javascript.

```
var containsOne = function(checkForOne) {
   return checkForOne.indexOf("1") >= 0;
};

var containsZero = function(checkForZero) {
  return checkForZero.indexOf("0") >= 0;
};

var addClassForOnes = function(element) {
  var text = element.textContent; 
  if (containsOne(text)) {
    $(element).addClass('has-one');
  }
};

var addClassForZeros = function(element) {
  var text = element.textContent; 
  if (containsZero(text)) {
    $(element).addClass('has-zero');
  }
};

var onDataBound = function() {
  var $gridCells = $('[role="gridcell"]');
  $gridCells.each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
    addClassForOnes(element);
    addClassForZeros(element);
  });
};
```

Finally color the cells with the following css

```
.has-one {
  background-color: green;
}

.has-zero {
  background-color: red;
 }
```